# Can't find symbol in setText

Tags: java

```
private void jToggleButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)         
{                                            
    Chaine=jTextField1.getText();
    jTextAreal.setText("Bonjour Monsieur"+Chaine);       
}
```

I have error : cannot find symbol 
in setText ??

Comment: i'am trying to make a simple interface with swing

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help sooner

Comment: Braj : no it's the same when you declare or not ,, thanks

Comment: @user3634466 You are absolutely wrong. If you are not declaring it then your can't use it. **In your case the problem is that the variable `jTextAreal` is not accessible here.**

Comment: @Braj yes i think so and this is the defalut declaration of NetBeans becaus i told you that i'm working with Swing.                                                          public class Principale extends javax.swing.JDialog {
      Object jTextAreal;

Comment: JTextArea jTextAreal = new JTextArea();

Comment: ok i used your declaration and the problem is solved , thank you very much

Comment: @user3634466 I have updated my post as well.

Comment: @user3634466 Try to avoid any such UI builder tool such as `NetBeans` if you really want to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

**Error Message: Cannot Find Symbol**

> When a Java program is being compiled the compiler creates a list of all the identifiers in use. If it can't find what an identifier refers to (e.g., there is no declaration statement for a variable) it cannot complete the compilation. This is what the cannot find symbol error message is saying, it doesn't have enough information to piece together what the Java code wants to execute.

Please validate all the variables declared in your code specially `jTextAreal` and `Chaine` and it **must be accessible** as well.

---

Have you declared it anywhere in code as shown below?

```
JTextArea jTextAreal = new JTextArea();

String Chaine;
```

Note : **Respect the Java [Naming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) Convention.**

---

I have collected all your comments

- it's the same (error) when you declare or not
- `jTextAreal` is an objet in my interface

There are two possibilities that may result in this compile time error **Cannot Find Symbol**

- Variable `jTextAreal` is not declared at all.
- `jTextAreal` is not accessible here.

---

Finally I got the it

```
public class Principale extends javax.swing.JDialog { Object jTextAreal;
```

It should be `JTextArea jTextAreal` instead of `Object jTextAreal` because `Object` class doesn't have any `setText()` method.

Comment: @Reimeus The issue is with `setText()` method that's mean `jTextAreal` is not declared at all in the code that will result in *Can't find symbol in setText*. Am I right?

Comment: but no , i said that the problem is in setText !!

Comment: @user3634466 have you declared `Chaine` variable any where in your code?

Comment: @Braj : i'm trying to work with a swing i means that i jTextAreal is an objet in my inteface , i just write this short code to make an evenment ,, could you understand me ?

Comment: @user3634466 do you have an access of `jTextAreal` in this class.

Comment: i declared it after i rempved the declaration ,, no difference !

Comment: @user3634466 Can your share your code specially the segment where your are declaring it. What about `Chaine`?

Comment: You must declare and make accessible __every__ variable you use in Java code. Also the Java code conventions warn against using capital letters as the first letter in variable names.